# Best way to execute method asynchronously in Android (compact and correct)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous

Say I have an Activity showing some content on screen. I need to execute some method (asyncMethod) asynchronously and when it is done, I need to update data on screen. What is the most correct and simple way to do this?

Currently the most simple way I know is using thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {         
    public void run() {
        asyncMethod();              
    }
}).start();
```

I'm familiar with AsyncTask, but it is more complex than using thread and for each method i need to run asynchronously there is a need to create new AsyncTask while this is greatly increases code size.

I thought about some generic AsincTask which gets method as a parameter and than executes it, but as far as i know it is impossible in Java to pass methods as parameters.

In other words I'm looking for most compact(but correct) way to execute methods asynchronously.

Comment: For that you can use a generic async task methodology. You can create Generic superclass for Async and call two methods from doInBackground and onPostExecute method. These methods than can be used in your activity by overriding these methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Handler` and `Looper`.

Most of the times, keep the Handler to the `Looper` of UI thread and then use it to post `Runnable`. For example:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
//later to update UI
h.post(new Runnable(//whatever);
```

PS: `Handler` and `Looper` are awesome. So much that I [remade](https://github.com/purijatin/InterThreadTaskTransfer) them for Java.

Comment: Internally, the UI thread keeps looping through its looper (i.e. it waits for Runnables added to its looper. If found one it takes it and then runs it. That is is how it runs your application for all mouse events, ui updates etc). So in your application, your normal thread does processing and only whatever has to be updated in UI, is sent to the looper of UI thread. Thus simplifying the whole process.

Comment: Wouldn't this create a Handler for the main thread looper, if `new Handler()` is called on the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

If you used the [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) design pattern, and made a generic AsyncTask that could run your "command" objects, you would need only one class for each task and the one generic AsyncTask to execute them all.  You could even go so far as to make a generic "command" that executed a method via reflections or some pre-defined interface method.

Comment: This still looks pretty much code for executing one method asynchronously. Need to create class which implements Command for each method?

Comment: You could use the pattern to create a "command" that executes an arbitrary method on any object via Reflections.  Or you could create one that is specific to each particular object.  Or, you could create an interface (or use something like Runnable) to and make a command that executes against that interface.  There are probably other patterns you could use, but the point being you can get as fancy as you want, but there are trade offs for each.